# Cop pulls a guy through a window from a car that's somersaulting over his head

Tags: identify-this-movie

What movie is this scene from?

[image: Cop pulls a guy through a window from a car that's somersaulting over his head]

Comment: This.  Is.  Awesome.  I love how he non-challantly steps out of the car as it's moving and isn't carried a single inch by the centrifugal force.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Agreed. Awesome.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - I would like to see that question on Physics or Skeptics, but I believe that stepping out of a moving car at a slower speed, if the car is spinning/skidding relatively close to center axis, is not that difficult a stunt.

Comment: If you see the very first few frames, the car is skidding (which can't be done at low speed).  Add to that the fact that when he shoots the tire the truck begins flipping on an angle, so it would never come straight at him.  Add to that the fact that after he pulls the guy out of the truck, it drops straight down on its roof after it's been rolling, which just isn't possible.  So, and I may be wrong, I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that the Laws of Physics were completely ignored here.  Unless Physics is different in India.  :o)

Comment: Ah Bollywood! [No one does absurdly awesome like they do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBlFCH0d3o4)! @JohnnyBones

Comment: @SystemDown - That made my year.  Two Thumbs Up!!

Comment: Guys, The "Stepping out of the car" scene-- already in [RED](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xonMpj2YyDU) ^_^

Comment: OMG....this kind of action scenes make me hate Bollywood action.

Comment: Anyways Chinese and sometime Hollywood also breaks physics law.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is [Singham (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1948150/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

Here is a trailer and around 1:58 you see this scene:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mp-XqCrCi6I

Comment: Singham is pretty B.A.! Regular Xander Cage from Bollywood! Noice.